# Angular 6 : How to display 2 dimension array

Tags: arrays, angular, angular6

This my array data that I get from service:

[image]

How I can use this array on my component

```
      <div *ngFor="let i of service$">

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4" *ngFor="let j of i">
                    {{j.title}}

                </div>  
        </div>

      </div>
```

My component.ts, I call getService() in my constructor.

```
 service$: any;
 getService() {
this.serviceService.get_service()
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(
      data => {

         this.service$ = data;

         console.log(this.service$);

      },
      error => {
          this.error = error;

      });
```

}

Comment: The html is valid. I guess you are not subscribing to `service$"`. You can do it in your component, or in the html -> `<div *ngFor="let i of service$ | async">`

Comment: It return error: ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: can you show us your component code? @Firdaus

Comment: I had edit my post

Comment: instead of calling it in constructor call it in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: still not working

Comment: remove `.pipe(first())`

Comment: @Exterminator it still not working

Comment: @Firdaus which version of RxJs are you using? Also please post your `service` code, you may not return an observable

Answer (score 2):

Use Async pipe which displays the data that comes from API.

```
<div *ngFor="let i of service$ | async">

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4" *ngFor="let j of i">
                    {{j.title}}

                </div>  
        </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: It return error in log : ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Answer (score 0):

Your service call should look like

```
service$: any;

ngOnInit(){
    this.service$ =  this.serviceService.get_service().pipe(
        catchError(error => this.error = error)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have some issues in TS I believe. First of all define variable like :

```
 service$: any[] = [];
```

Then remove pipe() and use below code :

```
getService() {
  this.serviceService.get_service()
  .subscribe(
      data => {
         this.service$ = data;
         console.log(this.service$);
      },
      error => {
          this.error = error;

      });
}
```

I hope you are returning get_service() some thing like this :

```
return this.http.get('YOUR_URL')
      .map((response) => response.json());
```

Your **HTML** looks fine to me.